# Passenger: RackEnv or RailsEnv?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, passenger

I am trying to set up a custom development environment that is not called `development` but rather extends the development environment with configurations that are specific to this environment. Creating this custom environment may be a bad idea as there may be some places that are referring to a development environment as `development`. Anyway, I'm trying to decide how to set this environment. In my virtual host configuration, I originally specified the `RackEnv` as development, but this is a Rails application, so my question is, should I be setting `RackEnv` or `RailsEnv` to my new `customDevelopment` environment? I am accessing the current rails environment using `Rails.env` if that makes a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RailsEnv. RackEnv is for hosting pure Rack-based applications.